# How to put more than one image in one line or one row in Text Web Part in SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, web-part, modern-pages, text-webpart

I have a text webpart in a modern SharePoint page. Now I have a need to insert 3 different images in one line or over one row. I tried putting the same , but the images are not staying in one line.

Please help on this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can't. The closest you are going to get is probably by adding a table with 1 row/3 cells and add the images to it but you will have to live with the table borders.

Comment: Do you want the images "inside" the text web part only? If not, you can add a new section with 3 column layout and add the images using Image web parts.

Answer (score 0):

The text web part doesn't quite seem to be able to set up three images to display on one line. You can divide the section into three columns and then add images to each column.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As per my comment in above comments section, if there is no strict requirements to add images in "Text" web part only, you can add a new section with 3 columns layout in your site and add the images using "Image" web parts (as "Text" web part does not allow adding multiple images in one line/row horizontally.

Follow below steps:

1. Go to your SharePoint site page
2. Click on "Edit" from top right corner to open page in edit mode
3. Click on **+** icon from left-most side of page and select "Three columns" layout:

   [image]
4. Now add "Image" web part in all 3 columns in newly added section by following this documentation: [Add a web part](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/using-web-parts-on-sharepoint-pages-336e8e92-3e2d-4298-ae01-d404bbe751e0#bkmk_addwebpart)
5. Inside each image web part, select/upload the images as per your requirements. You can follow this documentation for more information about Image web part: [Use the Image web part](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/use-the-image-web-part-a63b335b-ad0a-4954-a65d-33c6af68beb2)
6. Publish/Republish the page to save the changes and your page should look like this:

   [image]